# ¿Cuál es la función de la clase Collections en Java?

Tags: java, clase

Un ejemplo de uso de la clase `Collections` en un programa que controla una lista de tareas.

```
public void ordenarTareasPriority(){
    Collections.sort(tasks);
    showTask();
}
public void ordenarTareasFecha(){
    Collections.sort(tasks);
    showTask();
}
```

Comment: Collections es digamos una clase de ayuda para operar con colecciones. En tu ejemplo ordena la coleccion task. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html

Comment: Ojo, no es lo mismo Collections que Collection.

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ssa/library/j-5things2/index.html

Answer (score 2):

`java.util.Collections` es una clase utilitaria que trabaja sobre los objetos que implementen la interfaz `Collection` sin importar su backend (Arrays, Listas enlazadas, Árboles, Gráfos, etc.)

Todos los métodos de `java.util.Collections` son estáticos en su totalidad, por listar algunos `binarySearch`, `addAll`, `reverse`, `reverseOrder` trabajan sobre cualquier estructurada que implemente la interfaz `java.util.Collection`, esto quiere decir que para los programadores de `java.util.Collection`, no hay necesidad de implementar dichos métodos, que dependiendo el backend puede resultar bastante complicado implementarlos, así que `java.util.Collections` es de gran ayuda.

En tu anterior código

> ```
> public void ordenarTareasPriority(){
>     Collections.sort(tasks); 
>     showTask();
> }
> public void ordenarTareasFecha(){
>     Collections.sort(tasks); // malo 
>     showTask();
> }
> ```

el objeto `tasks` vendría siendo una instancia de alguna subclase de `java.util.Collection`... Puesto que utiliza el método `sort` también debe de implementar la interfaz `java.lang.Comparable<Task>`, cabe mencionar que los métodos `ordenarTareasFecha`, `ordenarTareasPriority` hacen exactamente lo mismo ya que utilizan el mismo comparador, en otras palabras u ordena por prioridad u ordena por fecha pero no puede hacer ambos...  así que el ejemplo tiene un funcionamiento erróneo.

```
public void ordenarTareasPriority(){
    Collections.sort(tasks, comparadorPrioridad); 
    showTask();
}
public void ordenarTareasFecha(){
    Collections.sort(tasks, comparadorFecha); //ok
    showTask();
}
```

Ahora sí, `comparadorFecha`, y `comparadorPrioridad` deben ser instancias de alguna clase que implemente la interfaz `java.util.Comparator<Task>`, deben comparar fecha y prioridad respectivamente, sobre los objetos de la clase `Task`, ambas implementaciones son triviales.

Para más documentación puedes ver los siguientes enlaces
1. [java.lang.Comparable.java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)
2. [java.util.Collection.java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html)
3. [java.util.Collections.java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html)
4. [java.util.Comparator.java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)